# TLS - Are signatures still needed?

Tags: tls, digital-signature, tcp

**The story:**

I'm currently writing a web service that allows for communications to be made remotely via TCP/IP.

I first thought about signing each packet using HMAC-SHA1 with a password, appending the signature to the start of the packet and then have the server (which also knows the password) verify the packet sent.

However, this means that the server would store the passwords as-is (without hashing it), making it very dangerous *indeed* for anyone who gain unauthorized access to the database. Furthermore, any sensitive information (such as a 'change password' packet's new password) can be hijacked via a man-in-middle attack.

I then read about TLS/SSL and decided to use it to prevent any man-in-middle attacks.

**The TL;DR:**

Do I still need to sign my packets when sending it over TLS? Or can I just send my packets over as-is? I read that it is not a good idea to send plain passwords (or their hashes) over networks. As such, I'm not sure if with TLS, it's better to simply send passwords over to the server for authentication, or to sign each packet with the passwords instead of sending them over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS provides both encryption and, in so far as you can trust the certificate authority process, origin integrity.  TCP/IP itself provides message integrity in the form of checksums and acknowledgments.  That should be plenty for most applications.

I hedged a little bit about certificate authorities because there have been valid-but-rogue certificates issued for the likes of Google.  I believe the highest risk is if some state (*i.e.* government) actor wants to compromise your data.  If you're transmitting financial information, you also have to worry about criminals, too.  If you have a particularly sensitive application, you might look into [certificate pinning.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)

Answer (score 0):

**Signing or not?**
No, you don't need to sign your packets. TLS's MACs will take care of that for you. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Data_integrity

**Passwords over the wire?**
Regarding not wanting to send a password over the wire: you may want to look in to mutually authenticated TLS. This uses certificate/key-pairs on both ends of the communication. It is explained here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication